# Highchart Gauge chart top portion being cropped/hidden

Tags: javascript, html, css, highcharts

I am using Highcharts (https://www.highcharts.com/) library to create a gauge chart

[Cropped Gauge chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OrRWD.png)

As you can see in the above image the gauge chart is being cropped at top.

Following is the JS Fiddle i have created with the same:

https://jsfiddle.net/4txnmdyp/3/

```
pane: {
    center: ['50%', '60%'],
    size: '200%',
    startAngle: -90,
    endAngle: 90,
    background: {
      backgroundColor: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.background2) || '#EEE',
      innerRadius: '60%',
      outerRadius: '100%',
      shape: 'arc'
    }
```

If I change the chart.pane.center to  ["50%", "80%"]  [reason for not doing this : i don't want the chart lower in the page]
or reduce the chart.pane.size to "80%" it works fine. [reason for not doing this : i don't want a smaller chart]

I see that svg is being created based on the val but the zindex val of that is very low 0.1
I suspect something is overalapping it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for this truncation was that you have an unusual `subtitle`. It is quite long, so that all chart elements fit on the screen, the solidgauge has been reduced. You forced it to double its size with `pane.size`, so the logic responsible for drawing the chart interpreted it to go beyond the plot (you can see this if you remove the subtitle). The solution is to set `subtitle.floating: true` which is recommended in cases like yours where it is in a different place and you don't want space to be generated for it in its original location.

**Demo**: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/8vhcg9zL/ 
**API**: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/subtitle.floating

Comment: Thanks @Michał the solution and explanation of the problem.